# How I can make a div that move on the X axis in a infinite loop?

Tags: css, infinite-loop, infinite

I want to know how I can make this possible. I want to make an infinite loop slider. But I can't get it to appear on the other side as soon as it starts to cross the right. Any idea, please? Here is how looks now[image]

And this is my code:

```
<div className='home-container'>
        <div className='slider-top'>
            <img className='top-28866' src={Home28866} 
 alt="Home28866Top1" />
            <img className='top-28866' src={Home28866} 
 alt="Home28866Top2" />
            <img className='top-28866' src={Home28866} 
 alt="Home28866Top3" />
            <img className='top-28866' src={Home28866} 
 alt="Home28866Top4" />
            <img className='top-28866' src={Home28866} 
 alt="Home28866Top5" />
            <img className='top-28866' src={Home28866} 
 alt="Home28866Top6" />
        </div>
    </div>

    .slider-top {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
animation: marquee-mobile 20s infinite cubic-bezier(0.53, 0.47, 1, 1);
width: 100%;
height: 5vw;
padding-top: 3vw;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-box-pack: start;

}

 @keyframes marquee-mobile {
 0%  {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
 }

 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML markup for better understanding ?

Comment: does it need to go left - right - left, or always from left to right?

Comment: Html has done, is part of a react component. Always the left to the right!

Answer (score 2):

You can double up the content

**Plain text:**

```css
[container] {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[marquee] {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  animation: t 3s linear infinite;
}

[marquee]:before {
  content: attr(data);
}

[marquee]:after {
  content: attr(data);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: inherit;
}

@keyframes t {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div marquee data="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the print">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Markup:**

```css
[container] {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}

[marquee] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    animation: t 10s linear infinite;
}

[content],[dupContent] {
    display: inline-flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

[dupContent] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

@keyframes t {
    to {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

[box]:nth-child(1) {
    background: hsla( 0, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(2) {
    background: hsla( 40, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(3) {
    background: hsla( 80, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(4) {
    background: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(5) {
    background: hsla(160, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(6) {
    background: hsla(200, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(7) {
    background: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(8) {
    background: hsla(280, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box]:nth-child(9) {
    background: hsla(320, 100%, 50%, 0.8);
}

[box] {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div marquee>
    <div content>
      <div box>1</div>
      <div box>2</div>
      <div box>3</div>
      <div box>4</div>
      <div box>5</div>
      <div box>6</div>
      <div box>7</div>
      <div box>8</div>
      <div box>9</div>
    </div>
    <div dupContent>
      <div box>1</div>
      <div box>2</div>
      <div box>3</div>
      <div box>4</div>
      <div box>5</div>
      <div box>6</div>
      <div box>7</div>
      <div box>8</div>
      <div box>9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** We're dealing absolute positioning here, So it will need a little bit of care if you're using padding/margin and the such.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't look like your example. Here is how looks like, I recorded my screen:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0Xj-L1vThk

Comment: Yes! Here you have a screen shot of my code :)
https://prnt.sc/133an0n

Comment: No a working code snippet on jsfiddle or Codesandbox, From that picture i don't see where the answer is implemented

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    width: 50px; /* Changeable*/
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s; /* Changeable */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Changeable */
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

/* Everything in @keyframes example{} is changeable */
@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:-20%; top:0px;}
  100% {left:102%; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div>Placeholder text</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you mean? I added "/* Changeable */" labels to anything that you can customize without messing up the animation. You can add your own css as well, of course.

Comment: No, I need wich the image to appear on the other side. Like the slider of this page https://extra-vitamins.com/